# How to create a custom debian iso file from Windows step-by-step?

Tags: windows, centos, iso-image

I'm using a Windows machine as a personal PC and I would like to know how could I customize a CentOS 6.7 iso file.

In general, what I'd like to have on that specific CentOS is:

- a .tar archive
- some `rpm`s (for example: `rpm -Uvh Percona-Server-shared-56-5.6.27-rel75.0.el7.x86_64.rpm`)
- `python3` instead of the default `python2.6` (a symlink would be enough)
- some `yum install`s (for example: `yum install perl-Time-HiRes`)

Can anyone tell me how can I have this done, **from a Windows machine** ? Thanks.

//PS: the reason for which I need this is that a client wont have access to internet and I have to provide him with a *ready-to-go* iso image.

Comment: I tried to figure this kind of thing out for quite a while back several years ago. I'd be really interested if anyone actually has the answer to this.